# Sql inserting arrays using split function

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have split function which will remove the delimiter from a array and insert into table like

```
     insert into tbl_Temp (column) select Data from  dbo.split('1,2',',')
```

It will inserting everything fine. Now i want to insert two arrays into two columns like

```
     Insert into tbl_Temp(column1,column2) ___(i don't know what to write)___
```

Using the dbo.split function, So that the respective column values should insert into column1,column2 by same order of arrays like
   **('1,2',',') ('a','b',',')**

my Dbo.split is

```
       ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[Split]  
       (  
       @RowData nvarchar(MAX),
       @SplitOn nvarchar(5)
       )    
      RETURNS @ReturnValue TABLE   
            (Data NVARCHAR(MAX))   
        AS
        BEGIN
        Declare @Counter int
        Set @Counter = 1 
        While (Charindex(@SplitOn,@RowData)>0) 
        Begin  
        Insert Into @ReturnValue (data)  
        Select Data = 
       ltrim(rtrim(Substring(@RowData,1,Charindex(@SplitOn,@RowData)-1)))
       Set @RowData = 
       Substring(@RowData,Charindex(@SplitOn,@RowData)+1,len(@RowData)) 
       Set @Counter = @Counter + 1  
       End 
       Insert Into @ReturnValue (data)  
       Select Data = ltrim(rtrim(@RowData))  
       Return  
    END
```

I don't understand how to proceed further...??

Comment: Why don't you work with table variables/parameters - types that are *designed* for working with multiple values - rather than passing around these made up strings full of delimiters that then need to be parsed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the following function to split comma delimited data:

```
create function dbo.SplitWithId (@RowData nvarchar(MAX), @SplitOn char)
returns table 
as
return 
(
    select substring(@RowData, n, charindex(@SplitOn, @RowData + @SplitOn, n) - n) as col,
    row_number() over (order by n) as id
    from numbers 
    where substring(@SplitOn + @RowData, n, 1) = @SplitOn
    and n < len(@RowData) + 1

)
go
```

It's an inline table function so it's faster than multistatement one. It also returns an id columns along with the data. You need a [numbers](http://dataeducation.com/you-require-a-numbers-table/) table to use it, but numbers table is useful in many ways.

With this function in place, your insert will look like this:

```
insert into tbl_Temp(column1,column2)
select f1.col, f2.col
from dbo.SplitWithId ('a,b,c,d', ',') f1
inner join dbo.SplitWithId ('e,f,g,h', ',') f2 on f1.id = f2.id
```

Comment: Numbers table?? Is this a table with auto increment column??

Comment: Yes, there is a link to Adam Machanic's blog in the answer explaining it in detail.

Comment: Ya i am understanding it like, it will insert serial no.s into all of my database tables??

Comment: Into all tables? No, it will just create a single table in the database, with a single column containing increasing integers. It won't affect any other table in the database.

Comment: Hey friend..What is the problem with the ':' in time data type in sql stored procedure??? every time it is showing incorrect syntax near ':'

Comment: Don't understand, can you give a sample?

Comment: sorry !! i found my answer sorry for bothering u!!

Comment: Suppose if i want to insert another column of datatype nvarchar?? like insert into tbl_tempt(column1,column2,column3)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52089/discussion-between-aj-sari-and-dean)